# What does “of” modifies in sentence below?

Tags: meaning

> I wear  the shirt with flower print of  my father.

In this sentence , does “ of” modifie shirt or  flower. Of It is know that the shirt belongs to my father but I wonder if I use this sentence in this way would it be grammatically correct ?

Comment: Please edit to provide a source for your sentence.  It is miswritten with bad spacing around the punctuation and doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: I changed my example to make it clear what I want to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is intelligible, but the word order is incorrect use.

Most English speakers will understand that `of` modifies `shirt` there; your father owns or used to own or made a flower-print shirt, and you often wear it.

Here is a better way to say this:

> I wear my father's flower print shirt.

If you mean that you are wearing it /right now/, then say:

> I am wearing my father's flower print shirt.

Comment: You say it is grammatically correct but  is not eaisly understandable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it" in your comment.  Which sentence or example is not easily understandable?

Comment: I wear the shirt with flower print of my father. This one . I know your sentence is very clear .

Comment: Just the opposite.  It's not grammatically correct, I didn't say it was.  I said it was intelligible or understandable.   To be correct grammar it would need an article: "I wear the shirt with the flower print of my father", but it would still be incorrect use / word order.   You'll likely want one of the two examples I give, instead.